# Google Logging List endpoint does not show application logs though the client library shows them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-logging

My Rails application needs to pull filtered logs from Google Cloud. I first implemented it via the official `google-cloud-logging` library, but the Ruby implementation is painfully slow, and each request takes 15-20 seconds. I tried the API explorer [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list) and it's much faster, however, the result is different - the REST endpoint does not return application logs, so the `resource.type=k8s_container` filter works with the client library, but not the REST endpoint. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: As you expect, the same log entries should be returned regardless of the approach. Absent examples from you, the only conclusion is that you're using different queries|filters. Please update your question with specific examples of the application code and the REST call and show the different (onfuscated) output that results.

Comment: I'm not a Ruby developer but I'm curious that the `google-cloud-logging` library is "painfully slow". It's entirely possible that it is, I'm just curious to understand why. It should be issuing the same underlying REST calls as APIs Explorer. The difference is possibly in the volume of data being returned or the way in which that data is being returned e.g. APIs Explorer will return a single page of log data but your code may be gathering logs from all ages at once.